# submenus of current menu item shows the current menu color

Tags: css, menu, navigation, submenu

the site has a menu item called portfolio with 3 sub menus which i have added as links in word press menu.**[the site](http://jointviews.com/portfolio/)** when we click the portfolio menu the sub menus text color also changes . i have commented out the current menu item css

```
/*ul#menu-main li.current-menu-item > a{
color: #fff;
}*/
```

so now the current menu items are showing different color not white .can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One last try. You have to select the direct child of the `menu-main` list.

```css
ul#menu-main > li.current-menu-item > a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You just have to add the child-selector `>` between `ul` and `li`.

Comment: now the problem is here .. http://jointviews.com/digital-marketing/social-media-marketing/ see the active menu text color in submenu :)

Comment: Add this: `ul#menu-main .sub-menu li.current_page_item a { color: white; }`